# Change the button of Downloadify Example script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [Downloadify Example](http://static.iiidefix.net/tools/Downloadify) to save the file on disk I do like this [link](http://www.pixelgraphics.us/downloadify/test.html)  but I want to change the button image to normal button of html code as below:

```
<input type='button' value='save' id='save'>
```

I can not modify this, anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
var exportButton = $( "#ExportButton" );

var exportButtonWidth = exportButton.outerWidth();
var exportButtonHeight = exportButton.outerHeight();

var flashObject = $( '[name^="downloadify"]' );

// Set the Flash object to the same size as my button
flashObject.css( { width: exportButtonWidth, height: exportButtonHeight } );

var exportButtonPosition = flashObject.position();

// Set my button directly underneath the Flash object
exportButton.css( { top: exportButtonPosition.top, left: exportButtonPosition.left, position: 'absolute', 'z-index': -1 } );
```

cc:randyburden

[link here](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify/issues/11)